When *should* a question be converted to a Community-Wiki?
I guess I'm still confused about Community-Wiki Questions, and there seems to be some conflicting information out there.
As background, I've answered a number of questions based on a common "root cause" in WSL2 that can be answered with some common suggestions and workarounds.  The questions are not duplicates of each other since each is about a unique tool, and each tool may have its own solution.
Rather than continuing to duplicate the information in each question that is common to the root-issue, I posted this question that I felt would be more useful as a single-source-of-truth.  This would allow one common question/answer to be updated with new information in the future. This seemed to me like a good use for a community-wiki question, but ... perhaps not?
Per the FAQ: What are "Community Wiki" posts?:

if you believe your post should be converted to a community wiki, you may flag it for moderator attention.

So I flagged the question for conversion. And while I was half-expecting a decline for some reason, the Declined-flag reason surprised me:

Declined - We do not mark questions as community wiki. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Well, okay:

It doesn't say that we never mark questions as community wiki. The strongest statement it makes, is "questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki."  On the other hand, in a more limited scenario, it also says that community-wiki questions shouldn't exceed 1 out of every 100 questions.

It also seems to have been written in a time when community-wiki questions were being abused in a number of ways - Bad questions were being left on sites and converted to community-wikis as a means of reputation denial, but the question remained. I'm in full agreement that those are not good uses for community-wikis.


Further, I'm confused because:

The FAQ provides guidance on how to request conversion of your question to a community-wiki.  If we simply don't do this, then shouldn't the FAQ be updated? (Yes, this is a Meta.SE FAQ, but the Blog entry pointed to in the decline message was also common to all of SE).

Mods still seem to be converting some questions to community-wiki.  Rarely, yes, as it should be.

I'm assuming, the most recent one was most likely converted because more than half the answers were duplicates or had other issues. I'm not quite sure that fits the intent of a community wiki (if that's the reason), but I definitely understand the decision in this case.

The second most recent seems to be the type of useful canonical question that should make a community-wiki, I believe.  It's more useful as one source that can be edited when things change in the future, rather than simply "piling on" new answers.

The third seems to have been converted as exactly the type of "Quick Fix" that the 2011 Blog warned about.  I don't disagree with the decision to do it - It makes sense here.  But that doesn't make it a "good community-wiki" - Just a bandage.




What's missing from all of this, though, is guidance on when questions can and should make a good community-wiki.  If it's there, then I'm missing it, and my apologies.
If we rarely convert, then when?  If never (which doesn't seem to be the case), then shouldn't the FAQ be updated?

Side-notes:

Perhaps my question is really a "quick-fix" scenario as mentioned by the 2011 blog post.  Perhaps it should be closed as "too broad" since it doesn't focus on one tool?  But in that case, is the solution to simply continue posting the same common information on each tool-specific question? A community-wiki question still seems to me to be a good (at least better) solution here.

I know the Flag-reply area is limited in text, and so the Mod probably couldn't fully explain the reasoning there.  That's part of my reason for posting here.

I also found this question on Ask Ubuntu that I felt was a very good use of the Community-Wiki question.



My opinion is very popular questions asked a decade ago, but the question is how to do a basic or frequently-asked beginner task. Questions that if they were asked now they would be closed as needs more focus, if not dupe. For example, I think this should be community wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/16217248

I am surprised there hasn't already been a discussion about this on Meta Stack Overflow before.

That is a surprising response on the mod flag because it's demonstrably false. It's not a frequent occurrence, but mods have and do mark posts (both questions and answers) as CW.

One example of a question converted to a CW post by a moderator just a few months ago: December 2023

@TylerH The flag response input is very short so a more accurate explanation would be difficult to fit in. But it's not completely untrue. I disagree with many of the recent occurrences, which I believe were made in error by my fellow mods. So as a general guideline, it's true that mods do not turn questions into community wiki. But it's also not never as some exceptions do exist.

@Dharman Sure, I don't expect anything as length and detailed as what you put in the answer. But something like "We only mark questions as community wiki in extreme/extenuating circumstances. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/" would be just about as short and also more accurate :-)

See also How to ask community wiki question?

Questions should be marked as community wiki only in extremely rare circumstances.
In contrast to answers which can be marked by the author as a collaborative effort, questions already are collaborative by design. Users can contribute by editing the question and writing new answers. The only tangible change that the community-wiki provides is a lack of reputation gain. Converting a question to community-wiki forcefully converts all answers to community-wiki too. Thus, this option should only be used when the question and all of its answers' authorship cannot be assigned to a single person. And this should be an incredibly rare occurrence.
The reason why the community-wiki questions exist is a historical artefact. The automatic conversion and the ability for the author to mark it as community-wiki themselves were removed a long time ago. Now, only moderators can do that and we usually don't have a very good reason to do so. The latest examples of it aren't very good examples and these questions should probably not have been made community-wiki. The WordPress question is a "quick-fix" because we don't really have a more appropriate way of dealing with this. I applied a historical lock to this question now, but I would not object to its deletion either.
Ideally, questions should NEVER be marked as community-wiki, but as long as the feature exists, moderators may use it for some exceptional "quick-fix" in the lack of a better solution.

This feature should not be confused with wiki answer lock, which prevents the addition of new answers to the question.

Thanks and to get to the core - "When should a question be converted to a community-wiki?", it sounds like the answer is "quick-fix only"?  Based on this, it sounds like you do not see any situation in which a user would flag their own question for conversion to a community wiki, correct?  Do you believe this is an SO-only policy, or SE-wide?  In other words, is there any reason to have the SE FAQ offer the guidance "if you believe your post should be converted to a community wiki, you may flag it for moderator attention?"

If this is SO-only, then we should probably update Make already posted question community wiki to reflect the site guidance. Or should we just consider reposting a similar version of this question on Meta.SE to see if the network-wide FAQ should be updated.

@NotTheDr01ds If you want to get a network-wide answer, you'd need to ask on Meta.SE. I'm afraid that the FAQ entry is vague on purpose.

This has happened before. Backlash ensured, CW was reverted.

The handy thing with having the question is community wiki is that they discourage some rep-hunting newbie from stumbling in on a high traffic canonical duplicate and posting some low quality crap answer just to farm rep. They can still post, but they will get no rep for it.

I've also petitioned for some of my questions to be converted to community wiki when I don't want any attribution for them. As in, when I want to use them myself for dupe hammer targets without being partial into giving my post more attention. Example - this is currently the 17th most frequent question under the C tag and a large part of the reason why is because I've repeatedly used and promoted the question myself, even though I wrote the original revision.

@Adriaan none of the posts mentioned in the OP have been made CW for reputation denial

RE: The latest examples [...] should probably not have been made community-wiki — the questions have been made CW because this is literally what is recommended in the reminder text of the relevant mod action popup (I wrongly recalled it was automatic). Making the question CW together with an answer lock makes technical sense because it allows low-rep users to edit the existing posts, as mentioned in the edit wiki privilege, linked also in the lock banner at the top of the question. This is, at least according to the current system, a valid use case.

@Lundin They won't lose rep either then though. So... it actually kind of protects people who do hit & run posting for rep farming purposes. I can't imagine that it causes much discouragement, because I can't imagine that such people pay attention enough to know they won't be making theoretical internet dollars.

@Lundin For something like that, a second-tier protection feature would be better suited. Change the current protection to "spam protection" and add a second one requiring 100 score in one of the question tags or 1000 reputation called "answer protection" (or some similar thresholds). Marking the question a CW post is a rather nuclear response for that small issue.

@Lundin There's nothing wrong with pointing people to your own question as the duplicate target. You should be awarded with reputation points for writing a suitable duplicate target. That's what this site is all about. Posts like that should not be made community wiki.
